# Is it legal to use youtube-api to download videos and convert to mp3

Tags: youtube-api

(site issue with youtube api)

Is it legal to use youtube-api to download videos and convert to mp3,include youtube icon refrenece that video belong to them,
Listen and when finish delete the converted mp3 include the video?

The idea is to pick 20 songs from youtube api search download and convert to mp3 and listen to music and when done listen delete all files.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as long as you're providing it for free, ( though you can't use the YouTube logo )

Comment: But what about all the copyrighted videos? example:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dK2tDK9grQ

Comment: No, that wouldn't be. However, if you're not handpicking copyrighted material, and leaving it in the users hands, you'd probably be fine.

Comment: Then i am not allow to save it on my server,all i can do is allow users pick bunch of songs listen and when done delete those songs from my server? PS you from youtube or just know the policy?

Comment: How should i know what is copyrighted through the YOUtube api search? as people can search anything.

Comment: You don't need to. You're providing a front-end to download mp3's of public videos.

Comment: Then sorry could not get it...in the end i am free to take video through api convert to mp3 and allow people listen,but not allow to offer download or sell. i am right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issues instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the video you intend to download and convert. There are videos that still have [Copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) claims and distribution without consent is ***illegal***.

There are some videos that can usually be subject for [Fair Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), but you'll have to check them accordingly just to be sure.

David Swisher's answer in this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-to-use-YouTube-to-mp3-converters) explains things very well:

> Such converters are merely technology, and technology is morally neutral; it is rarely illegal to use a specific form of technology.  It's what you do with it that makes it legal or illegal.
>
> You can use a YouTube to MP3 (or to MOV/MP4) converter legally to:
>
> - Download or convert one of your own videos to audio
> - Download or convert a public domain video to audio (one either produced solely by the federal government, or where the copyright has expired - which is usually 70 years after the author's death, or one in which the author has specifically released it to the public domain)
> - Download or convert a video to audio which has a Creative Commons license (as long as you follow the terms of that license)
> - Download or convert a video to audio within the specific and very narrow exceptions of "fair use" under 17 U.S. Code § 107
> - Download or convert a video to audio for educational use within the terms of the T.E.A.C.H. Act (if your institution complies with all of the criteria for availing itself of its provisions)
> - Download or convert a video to audio to create a new creative work specifically for the purpose of criticism/commentary or parody (under the very narrow criteria for those defined by the copyright law)
>
> If your use doesn't fall into one of those specific exemptions, then you have to request written permission from the copyright owner.
>
> This isn't specific to YouTube.  Any time you use copying technology (whether it be a photocopier, a digital camera, a scanner, copying by hand, a converter program, ripping software, etc.) the copyright law[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) applies.  The moment something is "fixed into tangible form" (i.e., turned into a video, recorded, written or sketched on a sheet of paper or napkin, etc.), it has a copyright on it, whether or not they actually file proof of that claim.  And outside of the specific exceptions named above, only the person(s) or entit(ies) who created it can determine how and where it may be used.
>
> So if you didn't create it yourself and own (or have the rights to use) all of the content in it, the only way you can do this legally is if it's one of those specific exemptions named in the bullets above.  Any other use would be illegal.

Comment: Thanks,but youtube-api doesnt return any copyright term so i can check before convert it to mp3.

Comment: Ahmm. I believe such copyright terms were implied for each video just by going through the [YouTube API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service). There is still a possibility of being flagged for copyright infringement for licensed videos since you'll be downloading and converting it's audio which will then be distributed (stored in the user(s) device(s)).

Comment: The audio not saving to users device,is saving to server - and can use for mp3

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be legal as if it is illegal it would be dumb for those web writers
PS YOU CANNOT SELL THEM

Comment: I don't plan to sell,just to use youtube as big database to take songs from listen and remove them.I don't like my phone using internet so much to run the videos to just play song.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely legal as long as your are not misusing  the videos, like publishing to other sites or earning money from that videos in any ways without the consent of the owner. In that case, you might face some legal consequences.
But, yes it is completely legal to use any downloader website to download youtube videos like www.collectyoutube.com , to download youtube videos in any format for your personal offline view.